# Javascript Cookie always exists

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have this one page where a cookie is created when a link is clicked, as the cookie is created using a javascript function called from the `onclick` event. I always have another button on the page which when clicked checks weather the cookie exists and the problem I am having is the cookie seems to always exist when I have clicked the cookie creator button. Below are my functions

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
                if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";


    checkCookies();


}

function getCookie(cname)
{
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++)
  {
   var c = ca[i].trim();
    if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
}
return "";
}

function checkCookies() {

    var cookie = getCookie("addon2");

    if (!cookie) {
    window.location.replace("http://google.com");
} else {
  window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
}


}
```

My two button are as follows;

```
 <a href="#" onclick='checkCookies();'>

<a href="#" onclick="createCookie('addon2', 'yes', 0);">
```

Why am i being redirected to stack overflow every time I click the first link without creating the cookie?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is this happening accross multiple browser?

Answer (score 1):

> Why am i being redirected to stack overflow every time I click the
>   first link without creating the cookie?

**You are being redirected because the cookie is persisting in the browser**

Clicking on your second link creates a cookie without an expiration.

Because your setting `days=0` when you call `createCookie('addon2', 'yes', 0)`

it is causing the `else var expires = "";` to always be called.

To really see what is going on. In Chrome hit F12->Resources Then select cookies. Here you will be able to see when the cookie is set (And see that it never expires). You can also manually delete the cookie by right clicking->Delete

If you want to have the cookie expire sooner so that you can see the effect within a few seconds, try some variation of this.

```
function createCookie(name,value,seconds) { //<----Change days to seconds
            if (seconds) {//<----Change days to seconds
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(seconds*1000));//<----- change days to seconds and *24*60*60*1000 to just *1000
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
```

and then with your link

```
<a href="#" onclick="createCookie('addon2', 'yes', 10);">Link</a> <!-- I set 10 seconds (Set whatever interval you like)
```

or

You could add this function

```
function del_cookie(name)
{
  var date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime()+(-1));
  var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = name+"=;"+expires+"; path=/";
}
```

And this Link

```
<a href="#" onclick="del_cookie('addon2');">Delete Cookie</a>
```

So you can expire the cookie from a link as VtoCorleone suggested

Answer (score 0):

Are you closing your browser and then reopening it?  If you just close the tab and then open another tab, the cookie could persist and still be there.

Add a 3rd button which deletes the cookie completely by setting the cookie to expire some time in the past (yesterday).  This will ensure the cookie is completely removed.  Then try clicking your "checkCookies" link again and you should be directed to google.